# nodejs https response is not received

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I'm using nodejs on windows 7. I'm experiencing strange behavior. The same https request that always gives the same response is most of the time not received by node whereas it is always received by a web browser.

The code is quite simple:

```
var url1 = 'https:<my url>'
require('request').get(url1).pipe(process.stdout)
```

The response is actually a chunked response, which is a big json object.

If I try this request on a browser, I always receive the anwser.
If I use the node request module (I also tried with https), the body is most of the time empty. But sometimes it is returned.

I receive status 200 and response headers are:

```
{ 'content-type': 'application/json',
  connection: 'close',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  date: 'Wed, 27 Jan 2016 21:01:59 GMT',
  server: 'My Server' }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe it is pipe issue. What about:
`var util = require('util');
  request.get(options, function(err, res){
 console.error('Err: ' + util.inspect(err));
 console.log('Response: ' + util.inspect(res));
});`

Comment: Not a pipe issue. I tried without pipe with avery basic code as you proposed. Same problem. No error. Status 200 but body is empty.

Comment: I just found out that if I explicity set header 'Connection':'keep-alive' it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 solutions to fix this issue:

1) Set header 'Connection': 'keep-alive'

```
var opts = { url: 'my url', headers :{ 'Connection':'keep-alive'} }
request(opts).pipe(..)
```

2) set to true KeepAlive option in https.globalAgent

```
https.globalAgent.keepAlive=true
```